# How to tally up checkboxes that are checked

Tags: formula, formula-field

I'm creating a report that Calculates DPMO (Defects per Million Opportunities). I need to tally up check box fields that are checked. How can I do this in a formula field?

Comment: This seems like it has **got** to be a dupe. I'm surprised I couldn't find one right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just counting checkboxes on Opportunity?

```
IF(Checkbox1,1,0) +
IF(Checkbox2,1,0) +
IF(Checkbox3,1,0) + 
...
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula field in the ***report builder*** and set it to a value of:

```
Checkbox_1__c:SUM + Checkbox_2__c:SUM + Checkbox_3__c:SUM
```

This way, you don't have to create a custom field and it only appears on the report using existing information.[image]